# How to classify unknown records using naive bayes algorithm

Tags: c++, c, machine-learning, data-mining

I am trying to implement Naive bayes algorithm on some real time data.I am aware of the rules of bayes but I am not sure how to implement on my data.My data looks like as below.There are total 2 labels in my data which are ok,fraud and testing data labelled as unkn.I need to classify all the unkn records as either ok or fraud by applying Naive Bayes Algorithm.How do I achieve this? Please some one help me.

```
1,v1,p1,182,1665,unkn
2,v2,p1,3072,8780,ok
3,v3,p1,20393,76990,ok
4,v4,p1,112,1100,fraud
5,v3,p1,6164,20260,unkn
6,v5,p2,104,1155,ok
7,v6,p2,350,5680,unkn
8,v7,p2,200,4010,ok
9,v8,p2,233,2855,unkn
10,v9,p2,118,1175,unkn
```

Bayes Rules:-

Posterior Probability of unkn being ok = Prior Probability of ok * Likelihood of unkn given ok.

Posterior Probability of unkn being fraud = Prior Probability of fraud * Likelihood of unkn given fraud.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming the row `1,v1,p1,182,1665,unkn` is interpreted as:

- `1`, `v1` = some identifiers
- `p1,182,1665` = features of your data point
- `unkn` = label, in this case unknown

With that notation in mind, your training data consists of all lines that have label `ok` or `fraud`, and your testing data is the rest. You have to calculate a priors and conditional likelihoods:

1. Prior probability of `ok` is the proportion of `ok` examples in the training data. The same applies for `fraud`
2. For each feature `f`, such as `v1` or `p1`, its likelihood given ok is the proportion of `ok` examples in the training data which contain the feature. For instance, `p1` is contained in 2 out of 4 `ok` examples, giving you a probability of 0.5.

For each example multiply together the probabilities you calculated for all of its features in step 2. Multiply the result by the probability in step 1 to obtain the (joint) probability of your example belonging to a particular class.

Caveats:

- Multiplying probabilities together will eventually result in underflow. You might want to add the logs of those probabilities instead.
- The algorithm I described works for discrete-valued features only. The continuous-valued features you appear to have above (e.g. `182`) need to be converted to discrete (e.g. by binning) or you need to come up with some other way of estimating the conditional probability in step 2. Google for continuous-valued Naive Bayes

Comment: I have around 410k rows in my file with these three classifiers.What do you think is the best programmatic method to solve this problem?

Comment: The relation consists of five attributes, ID, Prod, Quant, Val, and Insp. The first is the salesman’s anonymous ID, the next some product identifier, the number of units sold, the total value of the sale, and lastly, whether the human annotated transaction was deemed valid ok , invalid fraud, or unexamined unkn.

Comment: I think you are confusing the terminology. The three classifiers you refer to are not classifiers, they are labels. You have 410k data points, only some of which are labelled (`fraud` or `ok`). The rest you want to classify into two classes using a classifier. A classifier is a method (such as the one I described above) that you use to label the unknowns as either `fraud` or `ok`.
Many existing classifier implementations exist, google around a bit  :)

Comment: Hi Rester.. Can you go thru this link and suggest me whether it is correct way of implementation or not.Thank you.http://www.inf.u-szeged.hu/~ormandi/ai2/06-naiveBayes-example.pdf